# Install Prerender in Nginx or Django?

Tags: javascript, django, nginx, seo, prerender

[Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) allows you to [install](https://prerender.io/getting-started#install-it) it by either editing the [Nginx config](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802) or adding a [Django middleware](https://github.com/skoczen/django-seo-js).

What are the performace differences, if any, and which setup is better?

[image: prerender getting started]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emailed Prerender with the same question and the answer from [Todd](https://github.com/thoop) at Prerender was,

> You should set up the token wherever you set up your middleware. As far as which middleware to use, the nginx middleware lets nginx handle the proxy in an asynchronous manner so that requests from crawlers are never even sent to your Django server. Using the Django middleware, the requests will hit you Django server and then be proxied. Make sure that Django middleware uses non-blocking I/O so that requests to Prerender don't pause the thread.
>
> In either case, if Prerender.io doesn't have the page cached, Prerender will make another request to your server for that page to cache it on the fly.